# onChange react-select not calling my function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-select

I have the following react-select code which all works fine and sets my Formik state values.

```
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);  

    <Select
        options={myOptions}
        isMulti={true}
        name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
        onChange={(selectedOptions) => {
            let e = { target: { name: `myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`, value: selectedOptions } };
            handleChange(e);
            handleChangeIndex(index);
        }}
    />
```

My question is, during the `onChange` I also want to call another function: `handleChangeIndex` to set state values, i.e.:

```
  const handleChangeIndex = index => selectedOption => {
    console.log("inside handleChangeIndex....")
    const optionsCopy = [...selectedOptions];
    optionsCopy[index] = selectedOption;

    setSelectedOptions(optionsCopy);
  };
```

In my `<Select>` above, my function `handleChangeIndex(index)` is not being called as I am not seeing a console.log message but if I call the `<Select>` as follows with just my `handleChangeIndex` alone it works.

```
    <Select
        options={myOptions}
        isMulti={true}
        name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
        onChange={handleChangeIndex(index)}
    />
```

Can people pls assist with how to call my function as in the top `<Select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `handleChangeIndex` into `Select` directly, you are calling the function, which is returning another function ([currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)). Then `Select` is calling that new inner function when the values change.

When you call `handleChangeIndex` directly in the `onChange` in the first example you gave, you are only calling it once, which means you are getting that inner function, and then doing nothing with it.

If you then call that inner function with the `selectedOptions`, then it should work fine.

```
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);  

    <Select
        options={myOptions}
        isMulti={true}
        name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
        onChange={(selectedOptions) => {
            let e = { target: { name: `myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`, value: selectedOptions } };
            handleChange(e);
            handleChangeIndex(index)(selectedOptions);
        }}
    />
```

Comment: Brilliant - that solved my issue and also learn't about Currying - thanks.